# Git clone from clone

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repository from a server, and then I have cloned a second copy from my local copy.

Unfortunately I have deleted the first copy (from the server), and I have only the second copy. I would like to push this second copy to the server now. With a simple "git push" I got the message "Already up-to-date.", but the server is not updated.

I was thinking of deleting all the .git folders, cloning a new copy from the server, and then put my local copy into it. But this way I'll loose all of my logs.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to add a remote that points to the server location.

Comment: Use [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem) to change the URL of your `origin` from the deleted repo to the repo on the server.

Comment: setting up the origin from cmd prompt and push will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/yourrepo
```